# IF or CASE statement with sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Thats my table:

```
| ID | Value | Unit | 
|----|-------|------| 
| 1  | 5     | t    | 
| 1  | 700   | t    | 
| 1  | 612   | kg   |
```

I have a short questions on if and case statements in SQL Server.

This is my code:

```
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(t.Value),0)
 FROM test t
 WHERE t.ID= "1") AS Result
```

The problem is if i have a specific value in a column i need to multiply the value befor the sum operator. If not i need just the result i get above.

My first try is:

```
SELECT Result = CASE WHEN t.Unit= 'kg' THEN (IsNULL(SUM(t.Value),0) * 1000)
ELSE IsNULL(SUM(v.Verbrauch),0)
END
FRFROM test t
WHERE t.ID= "1"
```

I hope this make the problem clear.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to achieve. Please provide table structure, sample data and expected result.

Also I do not think you fully understand how aggregate functions are supposed to work
I would suggest you read the documentation.

Comment: Should there be a comma (`,`) after the first `Result1`? Also, you can't reference the value of another column by it's alias in the same `SELECT`, so `Result1` will have no context in your `CASE` expression. I don't, however, see the point of your `CASE`, as `Result1 / 1` and `Result1` (if it were to work, or it was replaced with the correct expresion) would both return the same value. A number divided by `1` is the same number, so the division is pointless.

Comment: My problem is that I need two different sum values. If value t.Column3 = '1' i need to divide the result Value in this statement: SELECT IsNULL(SUM(t.Column1),0)
              FROM test t
             WHERE t.Column1 = "Test"
               AND t.Column2 = "Test2") AS Result

Comment: You can put a case statement inside a SUM operator, like this: Sum(Case When Column3 = '1' Then Column1 / Something Else Column1 End)

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the `case` as an *argument* to the `sum()`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t.Unit = 'kg' THEN 1000 * t.Value
                WHEN t.Unit = 't' THEN t.Value
           END) as 
FROM test t
WHERE t.ID = 1
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what i needed. Works fine

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `'t'` is for *metric ton* and you are trying to calculate the sum by converting `ton`s to `kgs`, so you should multiply by `1000` when `Unit = 't'`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Value * CASE WHEN Unit = 't' THEN 1000 ELSE 1 END), 0) as Result
FROM test 
WHERE ID = 1
```

This will return the sum in `kg`s.
If you want the sum in `ton`s:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Value / CASE WHEN Unit = 'kg' THEN 1000.0 ELSE 1.0 END), 0) as Result
FROM test 
WHERE ID = 1
```

Comment: @Whiteneon it's not possible that both answers *work fine* because their results are different.